# Can't boot into OpenSUSE 12.1 with Zen-Kernel?

Tags: linux, opensuse

I've a dual-boot Windows 7 and OpenSUSE 12.1 box. I want to install the Zen-Kernel because I think it's useful for me but when I boot into Linux it didn't load the desktop but I get the emergency console. I didn't buy it but when I start xfce with xfcestart its saying no protocols specified and the screen went black. When I type "startx" from the emergency console it load the desktop and it seems to work except I don't want it. Is this an xfce issue with the zen-Kernel? I'm using 64 bit. I don't have any meaningful error in the log files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to boot into OpenSUSE by disabling the new systemd and add init=/sbin/sysvinit to the boot options and use the old system V to boot into OpenSUSE. There seems to be a problem with systemd and Zen kernel. Then I've remove Brasero and tracker-miner because it kills my cpu:

```
zypper rm Brasero
```

and

```
zypper rm tracker-miner-thunderbird tracker-miner-firefox tracker-gui tracker libtracker-
sparql-0_12-0 nautilus-extension-tracker-tags libtracker-extract-0_12-0 gnome-panel-
applet-tracker libtracker-extract-0_12-0 libtracker-sparql-0_12-0
```

This is my command line:

```
rw root=/dev/sda7 rw resume=/dev/sda6 quiet fastboot raid=noautodetect   
radeon.modeset=1 radeon.lowpower=1 radeon.dynpm=1 video=1440x900 acpi_osi="Linux" 
pcie_aspm=force thermal.act=90 acpi.power_nocheck=1 init=/sbin/sysvinit
```

uname -a:

```
  Linux version 3.1.8-zen+ (xxxx) (gcc version 4.6.2 (SUSE Linux) ) #3 
  ZEN SMP PREEMPT xxxx
```